# Can a modern C compiler optimize a combination of bit accesses?

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-construction, bit-shift

I would like `var` to be unequal `FALSE` in case one of the bits 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 or 15 of `input` is set.

One solution which seem to be fairly common is this:

```
int var = 1 & (input >>  1) ||
          1 & (input >>  3) ||
          1 & (input >>  5) ||
          1 & (input >>  7) ||
          1 & (input >>  9) ||
          1 & (input >> 11) ||
          1 & (input >> 13) ||
          1 & (input >> 15);
```

However, I'm afraid that that would lead the compiler to generate unnecessarily long code.

Following code would also yield the desired result. Would it be more efficient?

```
int var = input & 0b1010101010101010;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note that binary literals (`0b...`) are an as-yet non-standard extension to C.  They're due to appear in C++14; they might, therefore, arrive in C1x, but they're not in C11 (the current standard).  That isn't to say they can't be used; it is just a warning that not every compiler will support that, though all compilers will support 0xAAAA.

Comment: Note that your alternative does not produce the same result as the original; you'd need to write: `int var = (input & 0xAAAA) != 0;` to get the same 0-or-1 output.

Comment: Why would you want to write the first monster? If anding with a bitmask suffices, do so.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler for information binary literals were already proposed and rejected in C89 (in both C89 and C99 Rationale documents: *"A proposal to add binary constants was rejected due to lack of precedent and insufficient utility"*)

Comment: @ouah: I'd agree with those assessments, as of 1989 and 1999. If (and it is still an _if_) C++14 goes through and adds binary literals, then the landscape for C1x support changes dramatically. There'll be 'precedent' and experience with them. They'll probably be added to most C compilers for compatibility with the C++. The other interesting addition to C++14 is the quote-separators in numbers: `0xFFFF'FFFF'FFAB'7891`, etc. I'm puzzled that `'` rather than `_` was chosen. The use of quotes makes ad hoc parsers very much more difficult to manage (whereas underscore would be a lot simpler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `input` is volatile, the compiler would be required to read it once if bit 1 was set, twice of bit 1 was clear but 3 was set, three times if bits 1 and 3 were clear but 5 was set, etc.  The compiler may have ways of optimizing the code for doing the individual bit tests, but would have to test the bits separately.

If `input` is not volatile, a compiler could optimize the code, but I would not particularly expect it to.  I would expect any compiler, however, no matter how ancient, to optimize

```
int var = (input & (
  (1 << 1) | (1 << 3) | (1 << 5) | (1 << 7) |
  (1 << 9) | (1 << 11) | (1 << 13) | (1 << 15)
) != 0);
```

which would appear to be what you're after.

Comment: You might not expect it to, but gcc optimizes the code in OP just fine (assuming `input` is unsigned int).

Comment: @rici: I would expect that some compilers would find the optimization, but would not particularly fault a compiler that failed to find it.  I prefer to avoid such constructs myself, since the performance of code which relies upon them can sometimes be severely adversely affected by a seemingly-minor change.  If the goal is to test whether any of various bit flags are set, explicitly producing a composite mask may help make that intention clear.

Comment: The code in the OP could well be produced by macros.  (`SET1(input) || SET3(input) || ...`). I wouldn't write code like that; I'd give the flags meaningful names and use bitfields (obviously not everyone's first choice) but I've seen lots of code which uses MEANINGFUL_NAMES as macros, so to each their own. But it definitely didn't surprise me that gcc found the optimization. I expected it to, and was surprised that clang only got half-way there (see answer by @harold).

Comment: @rici: Indeed, macros are probably the most common way one would get such a thing, but on the flip side if the macros directly read from I/O ports (which is common with embedded systems), then optimization would only be possible if the headers defining the ports declined to make them volatile (*which is a common omission*).  If a future version of the header files declares I/O ports volatile *as is required for correctness*, performance may go from excellent to abysmal.

Answer (score 3):

Your second example *is not equivalent*.

What you wanted was (using non-standard binary literals):

```
int var = !!(input & 0b1010101010101010));
```

Or with hex-literals (those are standard):

```
int var = !!(input & 0xaaaa));
```

Changes: Use of hexadecimal constants and double-negation (equivalent to != 0).
This presupposes `input` is not `volatile`, nor an atomic type.

A good compiler should optimize both to the same instructions (and most modern compilers are good enough).

In the end though, test and measure, most compilers will output the produced assembler code, you don't even need a disassembler!

Comment: By the way, some compilers offer 0b as an extension so the op's example may work for their compiler.

Comment: @Vality: Ok, non-existant was too strong, changed to non-standard.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. +1 Good answer, this explains the situation throughly, particularly the need for the double !.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to depend on the processor and what instructions is has available, as well as how good the optimizing compiler is. I'd suspect that in your case, either of those lines of code will compile to the same instructions.

But we can do better than suspect, you can check for yourself. With gcc, use the `-S` compiler flag to have it output the assembly it generates. Then you can compare them yourself.

Comment: The instructions available are likely relevant. Many DSPs and some other CPUs have instructions specifically for dealing with interleaved bits. It's possible the compiler would try to use those instructions, especially in his first example.

Comment: Ah, ok, I'm not really into DSPs, so I don't know about their special abilities. But if you know, I'll take your word for it :-)

Answer (score 1):

The orthodoxical solution should be to use the forgotten bitfields to map your flags, like

```
struct
{
  bool B0: 1;
  bool B1: 1;
  bool B2: 1;
  bool B3: 1;
  bool B4: 1;
  bool B5: 1;
  bool B6: 1;
  bool B7: 1;
  bool B8: 1;
  bool B9: 1;
  bool B10: 1;
  bool B11: 1;
  bool B12: 1;
  bool B13: 1;
  bool B14: 1;
  bool B15: 1;
} input;
```

and use the expression

```
bool Var= input.B1 || input.B3 || input.B5 || input.B7 || input.B9 || input.B11 || input.B13 || input.B15;
```

I doubt that an optimizing compiler will use the single-go masking trick, but honestly I have not tried.

Comment: Why would you want to confound the reader with bitfields when you can just and with a bitmask?!?

Comment: They were created for this purpose, and of course should take meaningful naming. Readable and portable code. You can even create the desired bit mask with mask= { false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true };

Comment: Afaik, bitfields were invented to save bits back when computers had less than a mebibyte of memory, so that one would be able to store a value in three bits. The bit pattern that is checked in the question does not hint at the bits being independent boolean values, it hints at input being some numerical result, or a bit vector optimized into an `int` so that all bits can be manipulated together. Wrapping this representation into a `struct` deprives you of all these possibilities. You cannot compare structs, you cannot or/and them together, you can only assign them and access their members.

Comment: Then you can store the flags in an array of `bool`s (bytes) and `pand` them with SSE.

Comment: Yes, if it's the nonarithmetic type. But in either case I would never use a bitfield for it.

Answer (score 1):

How well this is handled depends on the compiler.

I've tested a minor variation of this code:

```
int test(int input) {
  int var = 1 & (input >>  1) ||
      1 & (input >>  3) ||
      1 & (input >>  5) ||
      1 & (input >>  7) ||
      1 & (input >>  9) ||
      1 & (input >> 11) ||
      1 & (input >> 13) ||
      1 & (input >> 15);
  return var != 0;
}
```

### Results

For x64, all compiled with -O2

GCC:

```
xor eax, eax
and edi, 43690
setne   al
ret
```

Very good. That's precisely the transformation you were hoping for.

Clang:

```
testw   $10922, %di             # imm = 0x2AAA
movb    $1, %al
jne .LBB0_2
andl    $32768, %edi            # imm = 0x8000
shrl    $15, %edi
movb    %dil, %al
.LBB0_2:
movzbl  %al, %eax
ret
```

Yea that's a bit odd. Most of the tests were rolled together .. except for one. I see no reason why it would do this, maybe someone else can shed some light on that.

And the real surprise, ICC:

```
    movl      %edi, %eax                                    #7.32
    movl      %edi, %edx                                    #8.26
    movl      %edi, %ecx                                    #9.26
    shrl      $1, %eax                                      #7.32
    movl      %edi, %esi                                    #10.26
    shrl      $3, %edx                                      #8.26
    movl      %edi, %r8d                                    #11.26
    shrl      $5, %ecx                                      #9.26
    orl       %edx, %eax                                    #7.32
    shrl      $7, %esi                                      #10.26
    orl       %ecx, %eax                                    #7.32
    shrl      $9, %r8d                                      #11.26
    orl       %esi, %eax                                    #7.32
    movl      %edi, %r9d                                    #12.25
    orl       %r8d, %eax                                    #7.32
    shrl      $11, %r9d                                     #12.25
    movl      %edi, %r10d                                   #13.25
    shrl      $13, %r10d                                    #13.25
    orl       %r9d, %eax                                    #7.32
    shrl      $15, %edi                                     #14.25
    orl       %r10d, %eax                                   #7.32
    orl       %edi, %eax                                    #7.32
    andl      $1, %eax                                      #7.32
    ret                                                     #15.21
```

Ok so it optimized it a bit - no branches, and the `1 &`'s are rolled together. But this is disappointing.

### Conclusion

Your mileage may vary. To be safe, you can of course use the simple version directly, instead of relying on the compiler.

Comment: Curiously, the `icc` code is essentially the same as that produced by `clang` and `gcc` for the equivalent program where all the `||`s are changed to `|`. Go figure.